# Regarding continuity of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space. Let $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function that satisfies the following condition:
Given  any $x,y\in X$, there exist a constant $M>0$ (depending on $x$ and $y$) such that
$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M \|x-y\|$.
Will this imply that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Did you try to see what happens in the special case $X=\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

When $x=y$ just choose $M=1$, and for all $x\neq y$,

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| < |f(x) - f(y)|+1 = \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|+1}{\|x-y\|} \|x-y\|$$

so it suffices to choose $M=\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|+1}{\|x-y\|}$. No assumptions on $f$ is needed to find $M$ (depending on $x, y$)

Comment: I'd like to explain this answer: Arctic Char points out that any function $f$ satisfies this condition. Since we know that there exist non-continuous functions $X\to\mathbb{C}$, your claim is false and the answer is a biiig "no"

Comment: @Arctic Char Can you tell what happens if the given function is equal to a continuous function on a dense subset?

Comment: Still it does not work, in my example, $f$ could be a function which is continuous on a dense subset, but is discontinuous. Your condition is too weak.... @Ma18